# How to tell sender they forgot the attachment without embarrassing them?

Tags: communication, email

So I got an email from someone reading "blah blah, X is attached".  However the email has no attachments.  Obviously they just forgot to attach X before hitting the send button.

How should I hint at this without being too blunt and possibly embarrassing the person?  Something like "Oops, I don't see an attachment, maybe my mail client blocked it?"

Comment: __Comments removed.__ Comments are for seeking clarification and otherwise improving the post they're attached to.  They're not for answers.  If you have an answer to the question, please post it as a proper answer.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

> Hey, is it possible you can resend this? I didn't get any attachments.
>
> Thanks!

Don't overthink this. No one's perfect.

Word it in a way which isn't accusational and you'll be fine. Don't say "you forgot the attachment" but just let them know.

Also, don't reply all if others were copied, just back to the sender.

Comment: I'd add that you also both can learn from this situation and do better on the long run. From my experience, I can say that it raises your chances to reach a win-win and avoid "I told you so" situations or waiting hours for a resent email when you select an asset management system outside email (think Droplr, InVision, Dropbox or Google Drive) and just exchange links. It may be difficult for a person you are working with to get it first (as well as it may for you), but it's all just about change and discipline. Just remember to explain clearly the benefits of your approach from time to time.

Comment: @enderland I really like how you pointed out the difference between "You forget the attachment" and "The attachment isn't there"

Comment: @ErlVolton passive voice on this sort of thing is helpful as it softens any "personal" touch.

Comment: +1 for don't reply to all, this is part of email communication etiquette

Comment: I personally don't see any problem with "you forgot the attachment". This is probably my "direct" culture speaking (as compared to "polite" american). :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Had I been the one to forget the attachment, and you replied "you forgot the attachment" I would think, "Oh, I feel like an idiot." Compared to enderland's response, where I would think, "oops, honest mistake."

Comment: With gmail this shouldn't happen, btw. It will pop up a dialog if it detects that you want to attach some files, but didn't attach any.

Comment: Yea, dont overthink this. Also keep in mind that certain file types can get caught in corporate email scanners, so the attachment could have been added by the sender, but was removed by a virus scanner.

Comment: Excellent answer - takes any 'it's your fault, idiot' aspect away.... Everyone can use the polite pretence that maybe the email system lost the attachments or something. Okay, so we all know they forgot it... But there's no blame or embarrassment

Comment: @JonStory Unfortunately the fact that you are making an excuse for it, implies that an excuse needs to be made. As such you basically make a bigger deal out of it than when you simply state that the attachment has not arrived.

Comment: It doesn't make an excuse at all - nobody explicitly blames anyone or anything. It just allows there to be a hint of 'it might not even be your fault'. I'd agree with you if the email specifically blamed the email system...

Comment: "I think you forgot the attachment" directly to the sender hasn't failed me yet, in any cultural setting (because hey, it's true, I really do think that you forgot the attachment). +1 for mentioning not using reply-all, in any case.

Comment: The answer is top rated (and rightly-so), but @Fredrik's comment should be as well. Corporate policy might block attachments with certain extensions, so saying "You forgot the attachment" might be untrue when the sender sent it correctly (without knowing of this policy).

Answer (score 10):

This is very culture dependent. And dependent on the person as well. The obvious thing is that you don't embarrass the sender in front of others unless you want to start a confrontation, so send whatever message you send only to the original sender and not anyone else.

From my point of view, I make mistakes, and if you find them, you tell me and I fix them. I'm happy if you tell me because that way the mistake gets fixed. Sometimes mistakes are embarrassing, but you are not embarrassing me by telling me, I am embarrassing myself by making stupid mistakes. And if you make mistakes, I will tell you and expect you to fix them. But that's just me. Other people will be different.

On the other hand, if you sent a message "Oops! Looks like you forgot the attachment (we've all been there!)" as suggested, I would take it as condescending and annoying. Again, that's just me. gnack who suggested it would obviously be quite happy receiving this message. So the same message to different people will be received differently.

For a sender whom you don't know personally, a neutral message like "I didn't get the attachment, can you resend it? " should be fine - if someone takes offense with that, it's their problem.

Answer (score 1):

I like to say "Looks like the attachment got lost in the mail, can you please resend?" It's vaguely humorous, non-accusatory, and very clear.

Answer (score 0):

> Oops!  Looks like you forgot the attachment (we've all been there!)

Something like that is always nice. It's informal so it's human-to-human and it fails to offend as you are admitting that it's something common that we've all done.

Comment: Reply like Clippy would?

Comment: @Gusdor "It looks like you are trying to send an attachment. Do you want help with that?"

Comment: I think that sounds childisch ("oops") and arrogant; "we've all been there" implies lack of experience.

Comment: The only place where this MIGHT be appropriate, is if the other person is still learning how to send emails. So I would not send this in a work environment.

Comment: I mean: Imagine a situation where someone like Linus Torvalds or [Alan Cox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Cox) get "Oops! We've all been there" by a 17 year old greenhorn kernel programmer who had just his first beer a few months ago. A truly funny situation that will probably make the 17 year old a subject of some of the finest humor on [LKML](http://lkml.org) imaginable.

Comment: You're also elevating forgetting an attachment up to a level of embarrassment that requires that assurance. And it's not even offensive, it's just so wrong that people will just be left wondering why you said it.

Comment: I'm finding it interesting (and surprising) that this answer is getting downvoted. Here in the UK this kind of mild self-deprecation is used very often in many workplaces. What is **really** surprising me is that some people are interpreting it as arrogant - to me it says the opposite. So some international/cultural issues coming into play here I think.

Comment: @AE there is a significant difference in _self_-deprecation and _others_-deprecation. Some people interpret this as a fairly condescending phrase to receive (myself included) which comes across as backhanded, childish, and basically communicates "wow you idiot!"

Comment: Good lord, you guys are really reading way too much into this. I'm glad I don't have to communicate by email with any of you lot!

Comment: @AE you may be right (regarding cultural differences). I'm Australian, which is culturally very similar to the UK.  I have seen my suggested phrase used a lot here and I've never been offended by it and to my knowledge neither has anyone else.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea people would find this answer _condescending_, _arrogant_ and _childish_! I'm a 35 year old swede, and to me this sounds just fine. Being a software developer, the phrasing `"Ooops, ..."` is often used as a "softer" form of `Error` or `Warning` in various places, so I'm used to seeing it and to me it communicates that this message was written by a human with at least some trace amount of humor and not just 100% plain boring business. Would love to see a poll on this :D

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for finesse here.

In situations where it's possible that somebody else could be responsible for the failure of the attachment to arrive (especially if that's you), the email should be phrased in a way that acknowledges that.

In situations where the subject is embarrassing, delicacy is required.

In this situation, the overwhelmingly most likely cause of the problem is that the sender of the original email simply forgot to attach the document. Forgetting to attach a document is not remotely embarrassing: it's not like forgetting to put your trousers on. There is no need to avoid being direct: just reply to that one person saying matter-of-factly that they forgot the attachment. It's not like you're accusing them of some heinous crime. The worst possible case is that they did include the attachment but your spam filter ate it, in which case, they'll most likely reply matter-of-factly saying exactly that.

Comment: "Forgetting to attach a document is not remotely embarrassing" - I don't agree - one needs to avoid the implication that the sender has **stupidly** forgotten to attach the attachment.

Comment: @AE How does matter-of-factly saying that they forgot the attachment imply stupidity on their part?

Comment: It doesn't have that implication for *you*, but workplace cultures and national cultures differ, as does the sensitivity level of individuals. In some contexts, telling someone they have made a mistake can be interpreted as rude (however illogical this may seem to you). For example, see [air crashes involving "crew members whose cultural legacy made them too deferential to communicate clearly that the plane was about to crash.](http://blogs.wsj.com/middleseat/2008/12/04/malcolm-gladwell-on-culture-cockpit-communication-and-plane-crashes/)"

Comment: @AE The question says nothing at all about the asker being in a culture where pointing out an error is either taken to imply stupidity or be rude.

Comment: So? I think it's uncontentious that workplace cultures and the sensitivity level of individuals also differ. As I said above.

Answer (score 0):

A great response would be:

Good afternoon,

Hi (sender), thanks for sending me this however, the attachment appears to be missing. Would you be able to resend it?

Thanks.

Best Regards,
(your name)

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace -- note that this question is from 2014 and already has an accepted answer. Also be sure to take a look at the more recent questions in need of answers.