# How to ask the boss for a file he forgot to attach to his email?

Tags: work-environment

My boss forgot to attach a file he has talked about in his mail. How do I respond to his mail asking for the attachment?

Comment: Asked and answered before here: [How to tell sender they forgot the attachment without embarrassing them?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35845/how-to-tell-sender-they-forgot-the-attachment-without-embarrassing-them)

Comment: If you're that worried about it, it sounds like you have a poor working relationship with your boss. The longer you wait, the better the chances are he will forget where he saved the file and it will make the inevitable task of having him resend it that much more difficult. Don't make things difficult for your boss.

Answer (score 13):

> Hello Bill,
>
> The email did not have the TPS Report template attached. Could you please send it to me?

This should do. Don't overthink this. You seem to be worried that the boss may get "offended" for pointing out his mistake, but that worry is unnecessary. This isn't a big deal, your boss will most likely send you the attachment with a comment, "Oops, sorry I forgot to attach it", and move on as if nothing happened.

Alternatively, you could ask the boss over phone/IM or just walk up to his office, but there really is no problem with sending the email.

Comment: +1 If you saw your boss drop a document when walking away from the printer, you wouldn't hesitate to tell him. This is not very different.